# Birkhoff's theorem with language expansion?

Tags: ct.category-theory, universal-algebra

Let $\mathcal V$ be a [variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)) (in the sense of universal algebra). Recall that [Birkhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)#Birkhoff%27s_theorem) characterizes when a class $\mathcal W \subseteq \mathcal V$ of $\mathcal V$-algebras forms a [subvariety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)#Subvarieties), i.e. when $\mathcal W$ is itself a variety in the same language as $\mathcal V$ which is carved out by imposing additional equations and nothing more. Namely, $\mathcal W$ should be closed under homomorphic images, subalgebras, and products. For example, abelian groups are a subvariety of groups.

But there are examples of non-subvarieties which seem "close" to being subvarieties, such as the following:

- Groups are not a subvariety of Monoids. But we can expand the language of monoids by a unary "inverse" operation, without changing the notion of homomorphism, to exhibit groups as a variety. Moreover, the adjunction induced by expansion of language is precisely the inclusion of groups into monoids, and its left adjoint.
- In a similar vein, commutative [von Neumann regular rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring) are not a subvariety of commutative rings, but after expanding the language by a unary "pseudo-inverse" operation [1], we exhibit them as a variety without changing the notion of homomorphism, and as above pseudo-inverses can be forgotten or freely added to obtain the inclusion of commutative von Neumann regular rings into all commutative rings, and its left adjoint.

I am curious to learn of more examples in this vein, leading to my

**Questions:**

1. Is there a standard term for a full, reflective subcategory $\mathcal W$ of a variety $\mathcal V$ which is itself a variety (with the same notion of homomorphism)?

Being a full subcategory means that the notion of homomorphism in the two languages is the same. Possibly the conditions need to be tweaked to stipulate in addition that the language of $\mathcal W$ should be an expansion of the language of $\mathcal V$, with the inclusion $\mathcal W \subset \mathcal V$ respecting this relationship.

2. What are some other examples of this phenomenon (where $\mathcal W$ is not actually a subvariety of $\mathcal V$)?
3. Is there a characterization of such "near-subvarieties" along the lines of Birkhoff's theorem?

[1] See Arndt and Mariano Arndt, Peter, and Hugo Luiz Mariano. "The von Neumann-regular Hull of (preordered) rings and quadratic forms." South American Journal of Logic 10 (2016): 1-43. [pdf](http://sa-logic.org/sajl-v2-i2/04-Arndt-Mariano-SAJL.pdf)

Comment: A similar example is inverse semigroups.  These can be described as von Neumann regular semigroups with commuting idempotents but you can adjoin the (pseudo)inverse to the language and define them by equations and the (pseudo)inverse is automatically preserved by homomorphisms. Also groups form a subvariety of inverse semigroups so your first example factors through this. Since commutative vnr rings are inverse semigroups presumably their pseudoinverse is covered here too.

Comment: I suppose that boolean algebras sitting among distributive lattices would be another example. But I'm not sure we've truly sampled the full diversity of the phenomenon.

Comment: Notice groups are also fine inside of semigroups not just inside of monoids but monoids are not fine inside of semigroups. The problem is somehow the identity is not really a needed constant for groups. You can formulate the axioms using just inverses and multiplication.  But for monoids you cannot axiomatize the unit without including it and that seems to be why monoids are not full in semigroups while groups are.   Of course that doesn't explain why semigroup homomorphisms preserve inverses.

Comment: Another example would be henselian nonunital (commutative) rings sitting inside all nonunital (commutative) rings -- see [Clausen, Mathew, Morrow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.10897), Section 3.